# Не понимаю как правильно присвоить новый адрес указателю аргументу функции

Tags: c++, c, функции, указатели

Есть код

```
void func(BYTE* buffer, int bufferSize)
{
    BYTE bt = 2;
    BYTE* temp = (BYTE*)malloc(bufferSize + 1);
    for(int i = 0;i < bufferSize;i++)
    {
        temp[i] = bt;
    }
    free(buffer);
    buffer = (BYTE*)malloc(bufferSize + 1);
    memcpy(buffer, temp, bufferSize);
    free(temp)
}

int main()
{
    int bufferSize = 25;
    BYTE bt = 1;
    BYTE* buffer = (BYTE*)malloc(bufferSize + 1);
    for(int i = 0;i < bufferSize;i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = bt;
    }
    func(buffer, bufferSize);
    free(buffer);

}
```

Мне нужно что-бы в функции память в `buffer` была освобождена и выделена память а после в выделенную память была скопирована память из указателя `temp`. В функции всё срабатывает но при выходе из неё указатель `buffer` ниначто не указывает а при вызове команды `free(buffer)` крашиться программа. Я так понимаю я как-то неправильно выделяю память в функции для указателя `buffer` отсюда вопрос как нужно делать правильно что-бы всё работало?

Comment: указатель передавать ссылкой `void func(BYTE* & buffer, int bufferSize)`

Comment: В си с++ все агрумента копируются,  в стек, так что читайте об этом, тогда поймёте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так, с передачей указателя (если у вас в самом деле С, а не С++. В С++ лучше `malloc` не использовать, не привыкать :)).

```
void func(BYTE** buffer, int bufferSize)
{
    ....
    free(*buffer);
    *buffer = malloc(bufferSize + 1);
    memcpy(*buffer, temp, bufferSize);
}

int main()
{
    ....
    func(&buffer, bufferSize);
    ....
}
```

Хотя лично мне больше нравится вариант

```
BYTE* func(BYTE* buffer, int bufferSize)
{
    ....
    return buffer;
}

int main()
{
    ....
    buffer = func(buffer, bufferSize);
    ....
}
```

Comment: передавать результат функцией - быстрее, но это приводит к риску забывания/запутывание сохранения нового адреса. Я-бы возвращаемые значение вообще не использовал.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Я и написал *лично мне* :) А адрес не всегда может быть новым. Тот же принцип используется во всяких `strcpy` — возврат переданного адреса. Или, кстати, `realloc` — он же не принимает адрес адреса :) А главное - в этом случае не обязательно использовать lvalue, адрес-то может быть и *вычисленным*.

Comment: функция, с гарантированным результатом `strcpy` записывает результат в память. А вы гарантию не даёте, что ваша функция изменит указатель, а не приводит его в неопределённое состояние. Это всё-равно что дать детям пистолет со взведённым. *про `realloc` - надо подумать.*

Comment: неправильное использование `realloc` - это популярная ошибка. Вы хотите свою добавить в этот список функций?

Comment: @AlexGlebe А вы хотите растить детей, старательно избегая давать им в руки спички? Можно, наверное. Только тогда они будут лишены радости что-то приготовить себе самостоятельно или посидеть у костра... Тогда, наверное, надо и `delete` передавать через ссылку или указатель — ну, чтоб уж точно не выполнили второй раз освобождение памяти :) Да, о проверках — простите, не я писал функцию, и не я результат `malloc` не проверял, я только говорил о том, как возвращать значение из функции. Тут претензии вообще не по адресу... А вообще — это все споры ни о чем, кому что нравится.